# Recording of .mpd Failed

Tags: video, ffmpeg, recording, mpeg-dash, drm

I am Not Able to Record a Video. The Stream is protected with DRM. But I don't know how to decrypt the stream. I am authorized users

https://pastebin.com/WVrTNaQQ

Please See the manifest.mpd file code and tell me how can I record the stream

I Used This Code
`ffmpeg -i https://linkofvideo/manifest.mpd -c copy output.mp4`

Output
`[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x563b95bc2000] Failed to seek for auxiliary info, will only parse senc atoms for encryption info`

I need to record video in the Highest Quality.

Comment: if you're an authorized user, and authorized to download rather than just stream then the content owner would need to share an unencrypted version for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851195/how-to-convert-mpeg-dash-mpd-with-drm-license-to-mp4

Answer (score 1):

When an encrypted and DRM protected video is 'recorded' or downloaded so it can be watched later or offline, it is not actually unencrypted.

The video that is stored is still encrypted and the app or browser playing the video still needs to request the key from the DRM system when it wants to actually play and render the video.

For the higher levels DRM security, which are increasingly the norm, the decryption and the playback is also all done within a secure playback path or secure media path and no other app, or even the OS itself, will have access to the unencrypted video.

As mentioned in the comments above, if the content owner wants to give you access to an unencrypted copy, they will generally have to share an unencrypted copy with you somehow.